# Getting two errors for password presence in activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, sinatra

I am testing my user input validation in my application and I am getting two errors in regards to my password presence.

This is what I have written for my model.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Slugifiable
  extend Slugifiable::Find

  has_secure_password
  has_many :posts

  validates :email, uniqueness: true, presence: true
  validates :username, uniqueness: true, presence: true
  validates :password, presence: true

end
```

Below is my migration table:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :email
      t.string :username
      t.string :password
      t.string :password_digest
    end
  end
end
```

Each time I run my application with no input it should give me three error messages: "Password can't be blank", "Email can't be blank", "Username can't be blank". Instead I get an extra "Password can't be blank" error. I am using a `password_digest` variable which is a salted hash of the users password once the data persists in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`has_secure_password` comes with its own presence validation on the `create` action. Therefore, validating the presence of `password` is redundant and is causing you to get two "Password can't be blank" error messages.

Simply remove `validates :password, presence: true` or add a condition to the validation for a specific controller action/other context...ie

```
validates :password, presence: true, on: :some_action
```

Comment: What does the on: attribute do?

Comment: @Kenkuts checkout [this explanation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#on)